# Even with slf4j, should you guard your logging?

Tags: java, performance, logging, slf4j

Help me out in a debate here.. :)

The slf4j site here http://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#logging_performance indicates that because of the parameterized logging, logging guards are not necessary.  I.e. instead of writing:

```
if(logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
  logger.debug("Entry number: " + i + " is " + String.valueOf(entry[i]));
}
```

You can get away with:

```
Object entry = new SomeObject();
logger.debug("The entry is {}.", entry);
```

Is this really okay, or does it incur the (albeit lower) cost of creating the static string that's passed to the trace method..?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

I'll try to put my two cents from another perspective

**What is exactly the benefit of parametrized logging?**

You just defer **`toString()` invocation** and **string concatenation** until really needed, which is when you really have to log the message. This optimizes performance when that particular logging operation is disabled. Check [source code for SLF4J](https://github.com/qos-ch/slf4j/blob/master/slf4j-simple/src/main/java/org/slf4j/simple/SimpleLogger.java) if not sure.

**Does parametrized logging makes guards useless in all cases?**

No.

**In which cases would logging guards be of use?**

When there are other potential expensive operations.

For example (in the case this particular logging operation is disabled), if we have *no logging guard*

```
logger.debug("User name: {}", getUserService().getCurrentUser());
```

1. We would **pay** the cost from `obj = getUserService().getCurrentUser()`
2. We would save the cost from `"User name: " + obj.toString()`

If we *use logging guard*:

```
if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
    logger.debug("User: {}", getUserService().getCurrentUser());
}
```

1. We would **pay** the cost of `logger.isDebugEnabled()`
2. We would **save** the cost from `obj = getUserService().getCurrentUser()`
3. We would save the cost from `"User name: " + obj.toString()`

In the later case, we would save both costs at the price of checking `isDebugEnabled()` twice when this particular logging operation is enabled.

NOTE: This is just an example, not trying to debate good/bad practices here.

Comment: Thanks fgelz, this is the clearest explanation so I changed my mind n the answer.  Makes you think that despite all the different frameworks, there is still room for innovation in the logging world, in terms of deferring expensive operations.. maybe with delegates

Comment: @MarkD JDK 8 Project Lambda is going to help innovation (http://openjdk.java.net/projects/lambda/)

Comment: You should also be aware that calling a varargs method (such as logger.debug(String,Object..) is actually doing under the covers logger.debug(String,new Object[...]). So if you don't wrap the calls, you're creating (then disposing) a new Object array each time you traverse this method, even if you never write the content out. If you have a highly performant system or experience memory pressure then this can build up over time; and the logger.isDebugEnabled() call will be in-lined by a decent JIT if used a lot. SLF4J specialises this for one and two arguments, but for more you'll get churn.

Comment: With the modern world of Java 8 lambdas they would be a very nice way to delay the method call, but unfortunately there is no easy way to provide this.

Comment: Looking into the implementation of logger.debug(), it will check the logging level by invoking logger.isDebugEnabled(). Therefore, we also need to **pay** the cost of logger.isDebugEnabled() in the first case.

Comment: @coder.chenzhi Correct. I just factored that out because it is the same in both cases.

Comment: @fglez I don't think they are the same when the logging operation is disabled. In the latter case, the logging operation will be skipped, so we do not need to pay the cost of the inner logging level guard. In other words, when the logging operation is disabled, they both need to pay the cost of logging level guard. For the first case, the cost is from the inner logging level guard. For the second case, the cost is from the developer-written logging level guard. Please correct me, if I am wrong.

Answer (score 21):

Writing and reading all those `if(logger.isDebugEnabled()) {}` will probably cost as much time as they save you.

Of course, calling the log method isn't free but the same is true for calling `isDebugEnabled()`. So you're paying more for each log statement that is active if you use this pattern (because the logging framework will check the level twice).

It also clutters the code.

In practice, I haven't found the performance penalty to be big enough to bother.

If logging is too slow for you, write an non-blocking appender that pushes the log events into a queue without only a few checks and use a background thread to process them.

Background: The standard appenders are all synchronized so logging in a multi-threaded application can cause lots of small pauses where all threads wait for a log message to be written to a file.

Comment: thanks that's what I think as well.. will await to see what the general conscensus though before I give you a plus :)   I like the tip about the appenders which could well be a problem for us.

Comment: Both "calling the log method" and "calling isDebugEnabled()" can **be actually free** with some JIT optimizations I think. I'm not sure, but if would be the person providing actual high-performance implementation for sl4jf, I would place an implementation with no-op method at rutime for disabled levels, so that JIT can remove the call.

Answer (score 8):

The guard is not used because of the string creation.

Instead, it is typically used to avoid a potentially expensive argument expression, something like `entry[i].retrieveExtendedDebugInformation().formatNicely()`. For that, logback makes sure the argument is evaluated only when the log message is actually printed, while log4j always evaluates the argument before calling debug().

Here the only candidate is `String.valueOf(entry[i])`, which is not very expensive either, so you can make an argument that this guard is unneccessary altogether.

Comment: okay - this makes sense and is another view on things.  So in your opinion it's a judgement call on whether to guard, and guarding should only be used on relatively rare (expensive) operations?.. the introduction of parameters reducing the amount of those operations..

Comment: Yes, and depending on how expensive the operation is guarding often only makes sense for tracing statements inside loops. One could even argue that if your debug statements are so expensive that they slow down the class even when you are on a higher log level, then you're not using log.debug right, in particular, you're probably doing `while(condition){log.debug(complicatedExpression); doSomething();}` while you should be doing `log.debug(complicatedExpression); while(condition){log.trace(simpleExpression); doSomething();}`. But i'm no zealot, i admit i'm often writing a guard instead.

Comment: "Not very expensive" is still expensive enough to make a difference for a program with lots of log-statements.

Comment: how logback could prevent arguments to be evaluated before method call ?

Comment: In log4j's `log.debug("Entry is: " + entry);` the argument has to be constructed before the call to `log.debug()` and therefore before the framework has a chance to determine whether the log statement is needed or not. To do that, `entry.toString()` is called, and that might take some time. Logback's `log.debug("Entry is : {}", entry);` doesn't have this issue, entry is a separate argument and its `toString()` doesn't have to be called before `debug()`. Hence logback has a chance to see that a log entry is not needed before calling `entry.toString()`.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with a logging statement like this:

```
logger.debug("Entry number: " + i + " is " + String.valueOf(entry[i]));
```

is that it will do a lot of work to concatenate values into a `String`, which is then never used if debug logging is off. So in that case, it is beneficial to check if debug logging is on before executing this line. When you're just passing parameters:

```
logger.debug("The entry is {}.", entry);
```

then it does not unnecessarily need to build a `String` that is never used, and the check is not necessary; just passing arguments to a method does not have a very high overhead.

Note that if you have relatively expensive expressions for the arguments in a logging statement, it might still be beneficial to check the logging level first.

Comment: You can handle expensive expressions by having them in the toString() method in an anonymous class so they are not evaluated until actually needed.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Yes, but that would make the code quite verbose.

Answer (score 3):

Please don't use the `if` statement, because every time I look at code like this

```
if (logger.isDebug()) {
   logger.debug("Of course it's debug {}", sadFace);
}
```

I cry.

I hope that the cost of creating the static string is so low as to be insignificant for 99% of users.

Comment: slf4j does not use the `{0}` construct.

Comment: If you're using a lot of debug logging, though, which most large applications do, it can be a lot of overhead. You're creating more garbage for the garbage collector to collect, and some systems already have enough pressure in that area as is. If you don't make any calls to get your param, and you only ever use a constant string for the param string, that's fine, until someone comes along and changes it to do something slightly less trivial. It's easier from a 'coding standard' perspective to just require the if statement.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative to `logger.isDebug()` is to use "lazy logging" or passing a lambda expression [[link](https://www.baeldung.com/log4j-2-lazy-logging)]:

```
logger.trace("The user {} has {} dollars available", 
    () -> person.id(), 
    () -> remoteService.getBalance(person));
```

Comment: This should be the top answer for anything Java 8+. It's *much* more readable and less cluttered than a guard, while offering all the advantages.